# FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] when I run .bat file in python to download data from kibana

Tags: python, batch-file, subprocess, kibana

When I download data from Kibana,
first I write the index json file ,then I run bat file to download data.
Here is the python code:

```
import subprocess
def RunBat(path,OutFileName):
    filepath=path + OutFileName + ".bat"
    p = subprocess.Popen(filepath, shell=False, stdout = subprocess.PIPE)    
    stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
    #subprocess.check_call([path + 'curl.exe', filepath], shell=True)
    return p.returncode # is 0 if success


path = "H:/lhy/20170710/test/"
OutFileName = "2017072100_0"

RunBat(path,OutFileName)
```

return error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-14-d979ed3f5955>", line 12, in <module>
    RunBat(path,OutFileName)

  File "<ipython-input-14-d979ed3f5955>", line 3, in RunBat
    p = subprocess.Popen(filepath, shell=False, stdout = subprocess.PIPE)

  File "d:\Users\DT217\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 707, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)

  File "d:\Users\DT217\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 990, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2]
```

the bat file is:

```
curl -u username:password -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data @./2017072100_0.json -XGET "http://support.derbysoft.com/elasticsearch/derbysoft-marriott-20170721/_search" > marriottadapter2017072100_0_result.json
```

I simple click the .bat file ,it is worked.
Thank you.

Comment: Why are you using a bat file at all? Why not do the download within Python itself?

Comment: If UAC is enabled, and your user account is an administrator, and drive H: is a mapped UNC path in your standard logon, then by default it won't be mapped in an elevated process, which uses your non-restricted access token. The logon session for this token defaults to using its own DOS device mapping instead of linking with the associated standard-logon device mapping.

Comment: In this case you can use the UNC path directly, or manually map it as drive H: in your elevated logon session via `net use`, or enable the policy to link the device mappings between these two logon sessions.